Problem with textTrainRandomForest() function
I'm trying to use the text R package to train a ML model with the textTrainRandomForest() function, but I'm encountering an error:
Error in `dplyr::bind_cols()`:
! Can't recycle `..1` (size 10) to match `..2` (size 5).

Here is the backtrace for the error:
1. ├─text::textTrainRandomForest(...)
2. │ └─dplyr::bind_cols(results_nested_resampling, hyper_parameter_vals)
3. │   └─vctrs::vec_cbind(!!!dots, .name_repair = .name_repair, .error_call = current_env())
4. └─vctrs::stop_incompatible_size(...)
5.   └─vctrs:::stop_incompatible(...)
6.     └─vctrs:::stop_vctrs(...)
7.       └─rlang::abort(message, class = c(class, "vctrs_error"), ..., call = call)

I'm using embeddings generated by the textTrain() function with default options, using the bert-base-uncased model on 2072 documents (rows in a dataframe, each containing single or several short sentences in English), paired with a factor variable with 8 levels (ranging from 2 to 9). The factor distribution is uneven (perhaps this is relevant to the error?).
I'm also using default parameters in textTrainRandomForest() (10-fold cross-validation, using all embedding layers).
Here's the relevant portion of my code:
item1_embeddings <- textEmbed(
  item1_data$Text,
  model = "bert-base-uncased",
  aggregation_from_layers_to_tokens = "concatenate",
  aggregation_from_tokens_to_texts = "mean",
  keep_token_embeddings = FALSE
)

model_item1 <- textTrainRandomForest(
  x = item1_embeddings$texts$texts,
  y = as.factor(item1_data$Rating),
  mtry = c(1, 10, 20, 40),
  min_n = c(1, 10, 20, 40),
  trees = c(1000),
  multi_cores = "multi_cores_sys_default"
)

I also tried running the code without specifying mtry, min_n, and trees, but the same error occurs.
Any advice on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

There is an imbalance of your y. When you are using classification, the model needs enough of each label to actually learn something, so that it can predict more accurately. You likely have labels (factor levels) that only occur 1 or 2 times. That won't work. It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from dput() or reprex::reprex() and any libraries you are using. Check it out: making R reproducible questions.
